# Boostrap - I want to apply class `form-check-inline` when the displays reach sm and further displays width. How can i do it?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply class `form-check-inline` when the displays reach sm and further displays width. How can i do it?

```html
<div class="radio-container mb-3 container">
  <fieldset class="container">
    <legend>
      <h4>Destino</h4>
    </legend>
    <div class="input-radio">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="opcao" value="cidade" id="opcao-1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="opcao-1">Cidade</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="opcao" value="campo" id="opcao-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="opcao-2">Campo</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="opcao" value="praia" id="opcao-3">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="opcao-3">Praia</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="opcao" value="montanha" id="opcao-4">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="opcao-4">Montanhas</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way would be to edit the source `scss` files and compile them. In case you just need a quick `css` for that, this should work:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .form-check-inline {
        display: block;
    }
}
```